# Electromagnetic Interference

Tags: power-supply, pcb, circuit-design, emc, electromagnetic

I am designing an SMPS with flyback topology. The PWM IC is viper.

I have a doubt that should I place the IC at the bottom side of PCB or both the transformer and the IC on the same side(top side) in order to get less EMI. As I know transformer will generate EMI and as the IC is operating at high frequecy it will also produce EMI. Or their placement would not affect the  generation of EMI that much?

Comment: Your question is too vague to answer. What transceiver ic? What pwm ic? What flyback transformer?  The side of the pcb should make little difference - layout and design does.  Think about your question and formulate it so we can give you a precise answer.

Comment: Which configuration are you copying and follow the evaluation board design as closely as possible with attention to layout and part selection ESR or p/n’s and magnetics https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/sales_and_marketing/presentation/product_presentation/cb/b4/56/93/d0/3f/41/22/VIPerX6.pdf/files/VIPerX6.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.VIPerX6.pdf or better buy the evaluation board 1st and learn how to probe with scope high frequencies as shown on this site with tip and coil spring on 10:1 probe. And AC ripple on output DC with a C coupled 50 Ohm load to scope.

Comment: There’s a few different ics in the VIPer range. So your changes don’t add much value yet. However, my general advice is to follow the manufacturer’s suggested components and layout.

Comment: That’s the best advice for every newbie. SMPS design has many intricacies in details.